Why isClassDeclaration finds interface declarations instead in typescript compiler api?
I can't understand why when I check the node with condition like
    if (node.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.ClassDeclaration) {...}

I'm getting interface declaration instead? But class declaration has kind 262 (FunctionDeclaration)
    @Visit(ts.SyntaxKind.ClassDeclaration)
    public classDeclarationVisitor(node: ts.ClassDeclaration) {
        console.log("class declaration", node.getText());
        const hasName = node.name && ts.isIdentifier(node.name);
        const className = hasName ? node.getText() : "";
        const implementedInterfaces = getImplementedInterfaces(node);
        return node;

    }

you can see output on screenshot
output
Can you please help me, how I can get class declarations using this condition, maybe I have wrong configurations?
I'm trying to create a DI container that can work with interfaces and inject instances of classes that implemented some interfaces by type in constructor, I've already figured out the main logic, but faced this trouble.
I tried to check other transformer libraries, but I can't understand the difference.
I also tried to use isClassDeclaration type guard function but it works the same

My guess is that the code is somehow mixing two different versions of TypeScript where the definition of ts.SyntaxKind has different member values (they really should pin all SyntaxKind members to a specific value, but they don't). Ensure you're only using one version of TypeScript.

thank you, my application was using typescript 5.4.5, and my transformer was using typescript 5.1.3
but for both there was typescript ^5.1.3 in package.json...
